# How to get ART in AOSP redirect stdio to logcat?

Tags: android-source

I want to get `stdout` and `stderr` from `system_server` to show up in logcat since a number of native libraries have no real awareness they are running in Android and I'd like to debug them by examining their logging. From what I can tell by default `stdout` and `stderr` are redirected to `/dev/null` for processes spawned in Android. I read that in older android versions you could use:

```
setprop log.redirect-stdio true
```

Which set `-Xlog-stdio` when starting dalvik. Recent Android versions using ART seem to no longer honor this property. Is there an alternative for recent Android versions that use ART?

I tried adding `/system/bin/logwrapper` to `service zygote` init command that starts the system server but I get this error:

```
Could not ctl.start for 'zygote': File /system/bin/logwrapper(labeled "u:object_r:system_file:s0") has incorrect label or no domain transition from u:r:init:s0 to another SELinux domain defined. 
Have you configured your service correctly? https://source.android.com/security/selinux/device-policy#label_new_services_and_address_denials
```

This error appears even if I disable SELinux with `setenforce 0`. Perhaps there is some other mechanism in ART I'm not aware of?